# limit length of string, set max length of string column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to limit usernames to 16 characters long.

I thought this would work:

```
create table user(id int unsigned auto_increment not null, username tinytext(16) not null, primary key (id));
```

but it doesn't

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(16) not null, primary key (id))' at line 1
```

Comment: Oh I just had to use `varchar` instead of `tinytext`. Why ?

Comment: Because tinytext is the same as varchar(255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `varchar()` is for:

```
create table user(
    id int unsigned auto_increment not null,
    username varchar(16) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: @theonlygusti . . . `tinytext` doesn't take a length modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Review syntax of data types here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

`TINYTEXT` does not accept a length argument.

`TEXT` does accept a length argument, but it doesn't do what you think it does. It just changes the data type to one of the flavors of `TEXT` that is the smallest type that will allow *at least* the length you request.

As stated in the manual page:

> An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done, MySQL creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to hold values M characters long.

So `TEXT(16)` will create the column as `TINYTEXT` because that's the least of the family of `TEXT` types that will hold strings of length 16. Another example is if you specify `TEXT(2000000)`, it would promote the column to `MEDIUMTEXT`.

```
mysql> create table t ( t1 text(16), t2 text(2000000) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> show create table t\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `t1` tinytext,
  `t2` mediumtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Notice the columns have automatically been changed, and they no longer have length specifiers.

This means the `TINYTEXT` column will still allow up to 255 bytes, and the `MEDIUMTEXT` column will allow up to 16MB. The text length specified is not a limit, but a guideline for which type is needed.

If you really want to limit inputs to 16 characters, then use `VARCHAR(16)`.